# Policy for getting Cost explorer programetic access

Tags: amazon-web-services

I am accessing AWS cost explorer functionality using boto3.But not able to get the policy (least privileges) for accessing the CE using programmatic access.

Currently I am using Full Administrator access but that is not advisable.

Answer (score 0):

[Actions and Condition Context Keys for AWS Cost Explorer Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/list_ce.html)

AWS Cost Explorer Service (service prefix: ce) provides the following service-specific actions and condition context keys for use in IAM policies.

Actions for AWS Cost Explorer Service:

```
ce:GetCostAndUsage
ce:GetDimensionValues
ce:GetReservationUtilization
ce:GetTags
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two Policies that you can use :

1. **arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AWSBillingReadOnlyAccess** - This gives read only access to the user and allowing the user to view bills on the Billing Console.
2. **arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/job-function/Billing** - This policy grants full access to the billing and cost management console. This includes viewing account usage and viewing and modifying budgets and payment methods.